# Session management combining a cash server and client-side session

Tags: php, session

In my guiding book, this statement I saw:

"Server-side session is a wonderful system, but if the number of servers becomes plural, the problem of whether the session management should be done will occur. One solution is preparing a cash server. By storing session information in not a session provided by a framework or programming languages, but the cash server, the information can be shared even though server increases.  This session management utilizing a cash server is usable in even client-side session, but as the result, scalable composition is easily created because the server side doesn't have any states."

In above sentences, the author says it is possible combining a cash server and client-side session.

However, I am not sure of the statement. What types of information is stored in a cash server in case of client-side session?    I can't imagine it.    And you know, server-side session is used in normally PHP.  I can't find apropriate tags, so don't be confused by php being selected as the tag in my question.

Comment: You probably mean cache server. What type of data is stored? Whatever you want. Your question is too vague, can you clarify what it is that you're having problems with?

Comment: I am just wondering the sentence in my guiding book, so it is not that I have a specific problem with it.    If anything, I want information about it whatever it is. And maybe would this question be deprecated here?